# Finding Worcestershire parents of James Rammell, husband of Elinor Orrosmit or Arrowsmith?

Tags: england, vital-records, 17th-century, worcestershire

Does anyone have information regarding the parents of James Rammell, father of Thomas Rammell, and husband of Elinor Orrosmit (or Arrowsmith)?

Both James and Elinor were born in Birlingham, Worcestershire, England. James was born in 1679 and Elinor was born 1683.

James married Elinor on Sep 4 1704 in St. Peter, Worcester, Worcestershire.

I am working on my family history and would be very interested in any information regarding these individuals.

Sources:

- "England Births and Christenings, 1538-1975," index, FamilySearch (https://familysearch.org/ark:/61903/1:1:ND72-ZZN : accessed 2 May 2015), William Rammell, 07 Sep 1707; citing Norton, Worcester, England, reference item 8; FHL microfilm 1,042,163.

Comment: You say James was born in Birlingham, Worcestershire in 1679. What is the source of that information?

Answer (score 2):

Until additional sources can be provided I will suggest that James was probably not born at Birlingham in 1679. I have checked the parish registers for that parish and there does not seem to be any Rammells baptised there around that time.

For that reason I suggest you investigate this [baptism on FamilySearch](https://familysearch.org/ark:/61903/1:1:NG9T-NX1) in the parish of Bishampton, Worcestershire:

> 4 Apr 1680, Jacobus Rammill, parents "Gulielmi Rammill & Mariae"

Jacobus is Latin for James, Guleilmi is Latin for William, and Mariae is Latin for Mary.

Of course, more corroborating evidence (such as records to do with probate, tax, settlement, etc.) is needed to determine if this is the correct James. However, James Rammell is a relatively uncommon name in Worcestershire so there is a good chance it is the correct person.